# Python - Extract Sentences - Off by 1

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to extract the sentences of a paragraph and print them out line by line.  It does a perfect job except when a period is following by a newline.  For example: the user finishes a sentence and then hits enter.  So there is no space after the period

The code considers this sentence to be part of the previous sentence because there is no space.  When it is printed out, they are stuck together.  So in other words, how can I alter the code in order to extract a sentence when there is no space after the period.  For example: **This.should.be.considered.five.sentences** because there are five periods but the code considers it as only one sentence.

This is the code:

```
import re

abbreviations = {'dr.': 'doctor', 'mr.': 'mister', 'bro': 'brother', 'mrs.': 'mistress', 'ms.': 'miss', 'jr.': 'junior', 'sr.': 'senior',
                 'i.e.': 'for example', 'e.g.': 'for example', 'vs.': 'versus'}
terminators = ['.', '!', '?']
wrappers = ['"', "'", ')', ']', '}']


def find_sentences(paragraph):
   end = True
   sentences = []
   while end > -1:
       end = find_sentence_end(paragraph)
       if end > -1:
           sentences.append(paragraph[end:].strip())
           paragraph = paragraph[:end]
   sentences.append(paragraph)
   sentences.reverse()
   return sentences

def find_sentence_end(paragraph):
    [possible_endings, contraction_locations] = [[], []]
    contractions = abbreviations.keys()
    sentence_terminators = terminators + [terminator + wrapper for wrapper in wrappers for terminator in terminators]
    for sentence_terminator in sentence_terminators:
        t_indices = list(find_all(paragraph, sentence_terminator))
        possible_endings.extend(([] if not len(t_indices) else [[i, len(sentence_terminator)] for i in t_indices]))
    for contraction in contractions:
        c_indices = list(find_all(paragraph, contraction))
        contraction_locations.extend(([] if not len(c_indices) else [i + len(contraction) for i in c_indices]))
    possible_endings = [pe for pe in possible_endings if pe[0] + pe[1] not in contraction_locations]
    if len(paragraph) in [pe[0] + pe[1] for pe in possible_endings]:
        max_end_start = max([pe[0] for pe in possible_endings])
        possible_endings = [pe for pe in possible_endings if pe[0] != max_end_start]
    possible_endings = [pe[0] + pe[1] for pe in possible_endings if sum(pe) > len(paragraph) or (sum(pe) < len(paragraph) and paragraph[sum(pe)] == ' ')]
    end = (-1 if not len(possible_endings) else max(possible_endings))
    return end

def find_all(a_str, sub):
    start = 0
    while True:
        start = a_str.find(sub, start)
        if start == -1:
            return
        yield start
        start += len(sub)
```

Comment: Splitting  string on '.' is trivial, but I doubt that you want '123.333.0.0' to be seen as 4 sentences.  I think you just need to treat '\n' the same as ' '.  This would most easily be done by using '\s' (whitespace) instead of ' '.

Comment: Why should the paragraph `This.should.be.considered.five.sentences` be considered as five rather than six sentences? The code explicitly handles the end of the paragraph as a sentence even if there's no period. Do you want that handling removed?